# uwp: how to pass Button click event to default handler

Tags: button, uwp, event-handling

I would like to handle the Button Click event, do something, and then let the default handler execute.

Here's what I have:

```
<Button ... Click="OnMoreClicked" />
```

And here's my handler

```
void onMoreClicked (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  ... do something ...
  ... continue with default button handler ...
}
```

EDIT:

The button activates a flyout, thus it already has a handler to do that and I want to ensure that handler gets executed.

EDIT 2: my example code was too minimal. See this, instead:

```
<Button ... Click="onMoreClicked">
  <Button.Flyout > 
   ...
  </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

And

```
public void onMoreClicked (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  ... do something ...
  ... call default handler to show flyout ...
}
```

Comment: Why no do this in the default button click handler, then call another function and pass sender and args to this function? And another question is why you need to do your logic process in two method?

Comment: Pardon me as I'm new to C# and UWP. I don't understand your comment. First, what "two method" are you referring to ? Second, how do I do this in the default button click handler - are you suggesting I subclass that handler ? If so, how. If you have a complete answer, please post and I'll give you credit :)

Comment: @PeriHartman: There is no such thing as a "default handler". Do whatever you want to do inside your `OnMoreClicked` event handler and don't bother with the "continue with default button handler" part. Or what is it that you are trying to continue with exactly?

Comment: @mm8: I don't know the proper terminology, evidentially (please advise). I'm referring to the handler that would execute if I didn't declare one. And, yes, I do want the "default" handler to execute after my handler finishes.

Comment: There is no default handler executed if you don't subscribe to the event. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @mm8 - Ah, I see. I simplified my example too much. In my case, I have a Button.Flyout and the "default" handler causes the flyout to appear. If I don't call it, there will be no flyout. I'll fix my example code.

Comment: *If I don't call it, there will be no flyout.* Yes, it will. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Click` event handler is called before the `Flyout` is shown.

So you for example change the `Background` of the `Button` in the event handler:

```
private void onMoreClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.AliceBlue);
}
```

...and still see the `Flyout`:

[image]

You may also handle the `Opened`, `Opening`, `Closed` or `Closing` events of the `MenuFlyout`.

Or use an `AttachedFlyout` and show it programmatically using the `ShowAttachedFlyout` method:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    //...
    Flyout.ShowAttachedFlyout(button);
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Button Content="Button With Flyout" Click="Button_Click">
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <MenuFlyout>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Edit" />
        </MenuFlyout>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
</Button>
```

Comment: @PeriHartman: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, but why doesn't it work when I use Button.Flyout ? It is strange that UWP wouldn't directly support this kind of behavior.

Comment: What doesn't work? You can't call `ShowAttachedFlyout` on a `Flyout` that is not set as the value of the `FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout` property.

Comment: Apparently my intuition is wrong, but I would assume Button.Flyout is implemented as FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout. I'm not seeing a reason it shouldn't be. But apparently it's something completely different.

Comment: `FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout` is an [attached property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/attached-properties-overview?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) that can be set on any element regardless of whether the class has a `Flyout` property.